# Keyboard recommendation

Tags: keyboard, hardware-recommendation

Has anybody found a good ergo keyboard for a Mac? I've been using an MS Natural KB 4000 for quite a while but I need to retire it and thought I'd look around for something that would work a little better in OSX (mute, volume keys, keys actually labeled for all things Mac-y).

I've been using an Apple keyboard for the last week and while it looks cool, it's just awful to type on for any amount of time. Since I'm a programmer that is an issue.

I checked out Logitech's site and they don't seem to have any Mac specific keyboards any more. Google's not helping out. Any coders out there have a favorite keyboard?

Comment: See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/what-are-good-keyboards-for-programming maybe?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Hardware recommendation ("let's go shopping") questions are off-topic for this site. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a coder. I'm a writer of prose and I type 90 words per minute, and like you, I can't stand Apple's keyboards. For years I used an ergonomic keyboard and the original [Microsoft Natural Keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MS_Natural_Keyboard_Pro.JPG) circa 1994 was the best for my needs. When I wore out my second Natural Keyboard, ultimately I determined that the issue for me wasn't the need for the ergonomic shape. Rather, it was the need for something with a deep, full, springy, clicky key travel, which I find much less fatiguing than typing on shallow keyboards. So these days I've gone back to conventional non-ergonomic keyboards but ones with full-travel clicky keys. The [Matias USB 2.0 keyboard](http://matias.ca/usb2keyboard/index.php) is my favorite and it's quite affordable. I also have a [Happy Hacking Keyboard Lite 2](http://pfuca-store.stores.yahoo.net/haphackeylit1.html) (OEM by Fujitsu, I believe) when I want to get totally minimalist. It's also favored by a lot of coders, I understand. It's been on the market for many years, and is reasonably priced.

[image: Happy Hacking Keyboard Lite 2]

With regard to a true ergonomic design: Although I have never tried them personally, the [Kinesis Maxim and Freestyle models](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/keyboards.htm) are available, and also [in a version specifically for Mac](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/freestyle_mac.htm).

[image: Kinesis Maxim Keyboard]

[image: Kinesis Freestyle Keyboard]